# How to preselect in Vue multiple select js

Tags: vue.js

This is the markup for my veu multiselect

and here is the code

```
<multiselect
   v-model="baths"
   placeholder="Bath"
   track-by="label"    
   label="label"
   :allow-empty="true"
   :options="options.baths"
   :select-label="''"
   :selected-label="''"
   :deselect-label="'Remove'"></multiselect>
```

Comment: I'd suggest providing a lot more details about your problem, especially the code behind the `multiselect` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just populate the `baths` data property with the data you wanted to be preselected.

```
data: {
    baths: [],
    options: {
        baths: [
            // baths list here
        ]
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.baths.push(this.options.baths[1]);
}
```

Also you need to set the `multiple` prop to `true`:

```
<multiselect
   v-model="baths"
   placeholder="Bath"
   track-by="label"    
   label="label"
   :allow-empty="true"
   :options="options.baths"
   :select-label="''"
   :selected-label="''"
   :deselect-label="'Remove'"
   :multiple="true">
</multiselect>
```

---

**See this example JS Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/0hLexkyz/278/